# JavaScript que altera permanentemente css do servidor

Tags: javascript, css

Primeiramente, peço desculpas se essa pergunta é muito vaga ou estúpida, mas eu realmente não tenho conhecimento o bastante para formular de outra forma.

Minha ideia é simples, criar um site onde, através de JavaScript, o visitante possa, por exemplo, arrastar e mudar a posição de um elemento na tela. Mas que essa posição nova que o elemento assumiu seja permanente, inclusive para os próximos visitantes da página, e não apenas no lado do cliente. Imagino então um script que altere parâmetros de posicionamento num arquivo css no servidor permanentemente.

É possível fazer isso apenas com JavaScript? Imagino que não seja possível por JavaScript normalmente ser uma linguagem client-side. Qual outra direção posso tomar, então?

Comment: Possível com JS é, mas o resultado "permanente" só vai ser visivel na máquina onde a operação foi feita (ou seja, não vai ser no "CSS do servidor", o que por si só é uma afirmação bem vaga). Se não é isso que você quer, melhor [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer com detalhes. Fica mais fácil você descrever a intenção e finalidade da aplicação que quer fazer, e não a maneira como está tentando fazer.

Comment: Isso é possivel com JavaScript para fazer o drag e guardar a posição final) e ajax (para falar com o servidor); alguma tecnologia no servidor para guardar essa posição. Como está a pergunta é muito ampla. Podias [edit] a pergunta e começar por uma das partes do JavaScript.

Comment: Enquanto fazia um codepen para explicar a aplicação melhor, acabei encontrando uma solução: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-draggable-element-persistence-with-jquery--net-7474
Devo remover a pergunta? Já que a solução do link resolve meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

As duas possibilidades principals são:

1. Crie eventos no JavaScript onde, após o usuário efetuar uma alteração, ele faça uma requisição AJAX, salvando então os valores no servidor da forma que você achar melhor. Tais valores são restaurados quando a página é carregada novamente.
2. Se as alterações não necessariamente precisam persistir a vida toda, pode usar o `localStorage` para salvar os dados no navegador e ler sempre que precisar. Entretanto, os dados serão perdidos se o usuário limpar, trocar de navegador, etc.